# What is the lightest KDE I can use on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, kde, desktop-environments

Default KDE is not running good on my PC and it's too slow.
I switched to Unity-2D and it's better.
Wanted to ask if there is a more simple, lighter KDE that would work better on my PC.

Comment: Do you mean KDE? Unity-2D is not KDE at all its Gnome.  There are other desktops too such as "Gnome Classic", "Xfce" which is used in Xubuntu and "LXDE" as used in Lubuntu.  If you want to know about other non KDE desktops edit the question to say desktop instead of KDE and we can include these.

Comment: well i'm new to linux so i'm not familiar with the terms...anyway it seems that the answers below can solve my problem and give better performance..so i'll see...

Comment: You should take a look at KLyDE and follow it's development.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely recommend installing the "kubuntu-low-fat-settings", which removes a lot from the default kubuntu-desktop installation. KDE will be much lighter after that.

However the low-fat-settings may also remove some thing which you need.

Some of which are:

- Turns off compositing by default
- Reduces the number of Krunner plugins loaded by default
- Reduce the amount of effects used in the window decoration
- Disables the automatic loading of various system modules – such as
  the free space notifier, Nepomuk services, and others

See this article for more info:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/09/kubuntu-low-fat-settings-speed-boost-older-hardware

RAM and CPU/GPU usage will be dramatically reduced by installing this package

To install the package simply run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-low-fat-settings
```

Comment: So at first i need to install normal kubuntu and then over it to install this "kubuntu-low-fat-settings"?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you do have an option here.

If you install  `kde-plasma-desktop` then it will gives only core of KDE and nothing else.That is the final possible light weight KDE you can get.

to install that open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
```

Then from the log-in screen you can choose your Session.

For more information [Ubuntu-KDE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE)

**Edit:** `kde-plasma-desktop` is just `plasma-desktop` in 16.04.

Comment: thanks gonna try both options and see what fits better...

Comment: yup! choose what best suits you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are interested in Razor-Qt. It's not KDE, but a very lightweight desktop based on Qt, the same framework KDE is based on.

Note that it has a more lightweight approach than Xfce for example, which can be good or bad, depending on what your needs are.

You can install it via PPA:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:razor-qt/ppa`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install razorqt`

Comment: Tip: Although your intention is good, this cannot be considered as a valid answer since is not answering the question, but giving an alternative. OP asked for KDE itself, and KDE itself should be given.